# Ruby: how to get all available years in a rails 3 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a lot of articles in my rails 3 app. To put links on the index page, how can i get all available years ( from created_at attribute ) in an array to do something like this

```
years.do | year |
 = link_to year, articles_path(:year => year)
```

any ideas how to do this with minimum effort (regarding the DB querys )?

Greetings,
Adrian

*EDIT1*: This might not be the best/fastest. But fl00r reminded me on pluck:

```
@years = []

Article.pluck(:created_at).each do | year |
    @years << year.strftime("%Y")
end

@years = @years.uniq.reverse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to the existing answers if you only want an array of years:

```
@years = Article.uniq.pluck("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at)")
```

that generates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) FROM `articles`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@years = Article.select("YEAR(created_at) as year").group("YEAR(created_at)").pluck(:year)
@years.each do |year|
  = link_to year, articles_path(year: year)
end
```

or, as @seph mentioned

```
@years = Article.select("DISTINCT YEAR(created_at) as year").pluck(:year)
@years.each do |year|
  = link_to year, articles_path(year: year)
end
```

Comment: This might do the trick. But i get a "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" error for the first line of your code.

Comment: it's just `group` not `group_by`, group_by is an ActiveSupport extension. a bit confusing :)

Comment: Couldn't get it to work for me. This worked though: `Article.select("distinct YEAR(created_at) as year").map(&:year)`

Answer (score 0):

This solution is highly dependent on your database, but it should be fast.

Create a class method for selecting articles by the date portion of their `created_at` timestamp. Here's an example for SQLite:

```
class Article
  def self.by_year(year)
    where(['strftime("%Y", created_at) = "?"', year])
  end
end
```

Then your controller can call that method like this:

```
@articles = Article.by_year(params[:year])
```

Your view code has a slight syntax error (`years.do` should be `years.each do`), but other than that, it looks fine.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But i think you got me wrong. What i need is an array of the available dates of the articles. I'd like to display a bar like in the code above to jump directly to those years. Like pagination based on years.

Comment: You're right. I misread the question. I believe that fl00r's answer gives you what you want, and perhaps you can use my answer in the model and controller.